# textpos and pause result in wrong order in beamer

Tags: beamer, textpos, pause

I use a textpos textblock in a beamer document.

I want to display content step by step, but the slides are in wrong order.

example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{textblock}{4}(1,2)
A \pause B \pause C \pause D
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

when generating the slides with pdflatex, I get those slides:
"B C D"
"C D"
"D"
"A B C D"

why does that occur, is there a simple fix?

Comment: Use the following code in the `textblock` environment if the sequential order is desired.
A \visible<2-> B \visible<3-> C \visible<4->  D

Comment: use of \only<2-> ... has the same results.

Comment: @Jesse Would you like to answer this question?

Answer (score 3):

Converting [Jesse comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186006/textpos-and-pause-result-in-wrong-order-in-beamer#comment430184_186006) into an answer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{textblock}{4}(1,2)
\only<+->{A}
\only<+->{B}
\only<+->{C}
\only<+->{D}
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```